# Correct way to declare multiple scope for Maven dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a dependency that I want to use in `test` scope (so that it is in the classpath when I am running unit tests), and in `runtime` scope (so that I can contain that in WAR/EAR/other packaging for deployment, but not affecting transitive dependency lookup for dependent artifacts).

A real life example is SLF4J's implementation JARs (e.g. `Logback`).  I want it to exist in the classpath when I am running tests, and I want it to be included in my WAR/EAR, but I don't want project depending on my project to include that in transitive dependency lookup.

I tried to use `<scope>test,runtime</scope>` but Maven 3 produces a warning:

```
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.scope' for org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar 
must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'test,runtime'.
```

What is the right way for declaring the dependency scope in such a case?

Comment: It's stupid. How am I supposed to use Guava in my tests? `@VisibleForTesting` is useful for me

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The runtime scope also makes the artifact available on the test classpath. Just use runtime. (See the Maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).)

To avoid having the dependency resolved transitively, also make it [optional](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) with `<optional>true</optional>`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback</artifactId>
  <version>0.5</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: However, the artifact is not available when compiling the test sources, which I believe is what he requires.  At least, that's what I'm trying to figure out.  I want it available for test for compilation and running, but not available for the main artifact during compilation (intentionally).

Comment: @voor I do not think you are correct. Runtime-scoped artifacts should also be available when compiling test sources. If that is not the case, I'd consider that a bug in Maven.

Comment: @Christopher From my experiments, it looks like voor is right: I get compilation errors in my tests when I use the runtime scope.

Comment: @jplandrain That sounds like a bug, and it goes against the documented/intended behavior. I would recommend you file an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG and demonstrate the problem with an example project, for it to be fixed.

Comment: @Christopher how to have import and runtime scope simultaneously?

Comment: @mwKART import and runtime scope makes no sense. import scope is not a true scope. It's just special syntax to include a dependencyManagement section declared in a separate POM file for easy reuse. I would advise that this is the *only* scope which would be appropriate to declare in a dependencyManagement section. Your actual scope (runtime, for example) should be declared in the dependencies section when you use it.

Comment: @Christopher. now in my project A's pom project B is added in the dependencyManagement section with scope "Import". How different this would be compared with having the same in dependencies section as runtime? I think i have very less understanding about the import scope. If you see this as the depth of my doubt. Can you share a good reference where i can understand this scope.

Comment: @mwKART POM A declares in its `<dependencyManagement>` section a dependency on POM B with "import" scope. In POM B, you have a `<dependencyManagement>` section with your actual dependencies and their versions. When POM B is "imported" into POM A, POM B's `<dependencyManagement>` section replaces the entry for POM B in POM A. When you want to actually use a dependency from POM B at a specific *real* scope, specify it as "runtime" (or whatever) in POM A's `<dependencies>` section.

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Answer (score 18):

Not sure if this would still help someone who is still looking for a simple way to do this - https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-dependency-scopes/ this link helped me add the correct scope. Here is the summary of mapping of scopes and the phases where we need the dependencies.

1. compile - build, test and run
2. provided - build and test
3. runtime - test and run
4. test - compile and test

So, when I needed the dependency during test and runtime, I gave the scope as "runtime" and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 16):

You can only define one scope value per `<scope/>` tag.

I'm afraid what you'd like to do cannot be achieved by merely using a scope. If you define a scope of `test`, it will only be available during tests; if you define a scope of provided, that would mean that you would expect that dependency for your project to be resolved and used during both compilation and tests, but it will not be included in your WAR file. Either way, it's not what you would want.

Therefore, I would recommend you have a look at the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), with which you can achieve it, but it will still require some playing around.

Answer (score 8):

Declaring a dependency with a [scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) of `runtime` ensures that the library is not available during compile time.

Declaring the dependency as [optional](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) causes a break in the dependency resolution process; projects depending on your libraries will need to explicitly include the dependencies themselves.

So the correct way to declare this would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.13</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```